# How to delay the sending of the data of the widget to the server side (to wait for a potential change in the input of the widget)

Tags: shiny

I have some widgets that receives a lot of user inputs in a very short period of time.
eg. a selectInput with multiple selection on which the user are clicking a lot very quickly

This causes unnecessary calls to the server side of the Shiny application.

Is there a way to set a delay before the widget sends its new data to the server? either application wise or on a per-widget basis.

I guess that would ask for some 'setTimeout' and 'clearTimeout' in the javascript.

If that's not available natively what are my options?

I have written a few custom widgets using http://www.htmlwidgets.org/ but I don't want to reinvent the wheel and I don't want to make a clone of the native widget because that would force me to track new versions of the  the widget and update the clone correspondingly.

Is there a way to extend an existing widget and override only some part of it (the part sending the new input to the server side), and keep getting the updates of this existing widget?

Another option would be to let the widget send its updated input every time there is a change on the widget BUT to tell the server to wait before handling it, in case a new input comes in. That would work for me as well.

NOTE: I don't want to use observeEvent/eventReactive

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use JavaScript then I would recommend using a setInterval loops stored in variables. I find them really handy for running functions in intervals and you can run multiple loops at the same time and tweak the timing for best performance as you can also close off and start up new ones. Hope this helps.